Why is interface: 0.0.0.0 causing failure in restarting unbound.service?
unbound.service runs w/o error when these 3 default files (created after installing unbound) are used:
root@DNS:/etc/unbound# cat unbound.conf
# Unbound configuration file for Debian.
#
# See the unbound.conf(5) man page.
#
# See /usr/share/doc/unbound/examples/unbound.conf for a commented
# reference config file.
#
# The following line includes additional configuration files from the
# /etc/unbound/unbound.conf.d directory.
include-toplevel: "/etc/unbound/unbound.conf.d/*.conf"
root@DNS:/etc/unbound# cat unbound.conf.d/remote-control.conf 
remote-control:
  control-enable: yes
  # by default the control interface is is 127.0.0.1 and ::1 and port 8953
  # it is possible to use a unix socket too
  control-interface: /run/unbound.ctl
root@DNS:/etc/unbound# cat unbound.conf.d/root-auto-trust-anchor-file.conf 
server:
    # The following line will configure unbound to perform cryptographic
    # DNSSEC validation using the root trust anchor.
    auto-trust-anchor-file: "/var/lib/unbound/root.key"

However, when these 3 files are removed and the content of /etc/unbound/unbound.conf made to contain
# unbound.conf(5) config file for unbound(8).
server:
    directory: "/etc/unbound"
    username: "unbound"
    # make sure unbound can access entropy from inside the chroot.
    # e.g. on linux the use these commands (on BSD, devfs(8) is used):
    #      mount --bind -n /dev/urandom /etc/unbound/dev/urandom
    # and  mount --bind -n /dev/log /etc/unbound/dev/log
    #chroot: "/etc/unbound"
    # logfile: "/etc/unbound/unbound.log"  #uncomment to use logfile.
    pidfile: "/etc/unbound/unbound.pid"
    # verbosity: 1      # uncomment and increase to get more logging.
    # listen on all interfaces, answer queries from the local subnet.
    interface: 0.0.0.0
    interface: ::0
    access-control: 10.0.0.0/8 allow
    #access-control: 2001:DB8::/64 allow

unbound.service fails to restart using service unbound restart. e.g.
root@DNS:/etc/unbound# service unbound restart
Job for unbound.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status unbound.service" and "journalctl -xeu unbound.service" for details.
root@DNS:/etc/unbound# systemctl status unbound.service
× unbound.service - Unbound DNS server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/unbound.service; disabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2024-10-28 16:01:59 UTC; 18s ago
   Duration: 50min 13.453s
       Docs: man:unbound(8)
    Process: 3385 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/unbound-helper chroot_setup (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 3388 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/unbound-helper root_trust_anchor_update (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 3391 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/unbound -d -p $DAEMON_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    Process: 3393 ExecStopPost=/usr/libexec/unbound-helper chroot_teardown (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 3391 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 168ms

Oct 28 16:01:59 DNS systemd[1]: unbound.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Oct 28 16:01:59 DNS systemd[1]: unbound.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 28 16:01:59 DNS systemd[1]: unbound.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 28 16:01:59 DNS systemd[1]: Failed to start unbound.service - Unbound DNS server.

To troubleshoot, I commented out every line, followed by uncommenting each line until unbound.service failed to restart. I discovered that the line interface: 0.0.0.0 is the cause of the error. I can't figure out why 0.0.0.0 is causing the issue. Why is this ip address causing this issue?
System:

Unbound version: 1.19.2
OS:  Linux DNS 6.1.63 #218 SMP Thu Nov 30 20:48:04 CST 2023 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux in Ubuntu Server 24.04.1
unbound -V output:

root@DNS::/etc/unbound# unbound -V
Version 1.19.2

Configure line: --build=aarch64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --includedir=${prefix}/include --mandir=${prefix}/share/man --infodir=${prefix}/share/info --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --disable-option-checking --disable-silent-rules --libdir=${prefix}/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu --runstatedir=/run --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking --with-pythonmodule --with-pyunbound --enable-subnet --enable-dnstap --enable-systemd --enable-cachedb --with-libhiredis --with-libnghttp2 --with-chroot-dir= --with-dnstap-socket-path=/run/dnstap.sock --disable-rpath --with-pidfile=/run/unbound.pid --with-libevent --enable-tfo-client --with-rootkey-file=/usr/share/dns/root.key --disable-flto --enable-tfo-server
Linked libs: libevent 2.1.12-stable (it uses epoll), OpenSSL 3.0.13 30 Jan 2024
Linked modules: dns64 python cachedb subnetcache respip validator iterator
TCP Fastopen feature available


BSD licensed, see LICENSE in source package for details.
Report bugs to unbound-bugs@nlnetlabs.nl or https://github.com/NLnetLabs/unbound/issues

Update:
root@DNS:/etc/unbound# unbound -d -vv -c /etc/unbound/unbound.conf
[1730176049] unbound[4263:0] notice: Start of unbound 1.19.2.
[1730176049] unbound[4263:0] error: can't bind socket: Address already in use for 0.0.0.0 port 53
[1730176049] unbound[4263:0] fatal error: could not open ports


If you don't want to use the chroot feature, try and disable it explicitly: chroot: "". Also make sure a user named unbound exists: id unbound. To quickly test if the missing user is the problem, you can try and temporarily start the server adding user: "" to the configuration file.

Also: unbound -d -vv -c /etc/unbound/unbound.conf to start the service in debug mode, which possibly will give some insight. If these suggestions don't help please post more of the journal: journalctl --no-pager -n50 -u unbound.service

Is that config file supposed to be in YAML? If so, it probably shouldn't have duplicate keys: interface: 0.0.0.0
interface: ::0

@muru Interface to use to connect to the network. This interface is listened to for queries from clients, and answers to clients are given from it. Can be given multiple times to work on several interfaces. If none are given the default is to listen on localhost.

@kos After implementing your comments, I have added the results from unbound -d -vv -c /etc/unbound/unbound.conf. It seems that there is a port conflict, 53 is already in used.

Ah yes, it all comes back to your previous question: on port 53 you have already systemd-resolve's stub resolver listening. It would be safer at this point to configure the server using another port and, once everything is working, disable the stub resolver and start unbound on port 53.

@muru I don't think it's YAML. It just happens to resemble YAML, the man page also suggests using duplicate keys, and doesn't mention YAML anywhere in the page

@kos Thanks. I discovered another error. unbound[4313:0] error: Could not open logfile /etc/unbound/unbound.log: Permission denied. How do I to resolve this issue? The file exists and its permissions are: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct 29 04:47 unbound.log I tried changing username to "root" and it worked. Is it safe to use root as username?

Ok judging from the docs it appears as though /etc/unbound should generally be fully accessible by the unbound user, so to my understanding it should be ok to just sudo chown unbound: /etc/unbound, and revert to running the server as the unbound user (which is definetly advisable)

@kos I don't think it is a good practice to change ownership of any file or directory within /etc from root to some other user. root ought to be the owner always. Is there another way around this ownership issue?

I agree it's atypical, however Unbound's documentation itself seems to suggest a similar setup. If you look at the first example, they're running the server as unbound, yet they're setting the log file to /etc/unbound/unbound.log, and if you look through the documentation it appears as though unbound should be able to write to the directory for some stuff.

You could be less lenient and make /etc/unbound 775 owned by root:unbound and let Unbound itself create the file, but I don't think it would be much different than leaving the full ownership to Unbound. Note that some files in /etc are to be editable by non-root users (as in usually the user that runs the thing usually has group ownership on the configuration file), so that is not really uncommon.

You can try and just leave /etc/unbound fully root-owned and just give group ownership to /etc/unbound/unbound.log (root:unbound 664), however again, the documentation suggests /etc/unbound should be writeable by unbound.

error: can't bind socket: Address already in use for 0.0.0.0 port 53

This is likely due to systemd-resolved's stub DNS listener listening on the same address / port (as hinted at also by your previous question).
The logical course of action would be:

Configuring Unbound to start on a different port (even a high one, just for testing), by adding, say, port: 3000 to /etc/unbound/unbound.conf;
Completing Unbound's configuration;
Starting Unbound:
systemctl start unbound


Testing DNS resolution on port #3000 using dig -p3000 [...];
Once everything is working, disabling systemd-resolved's listener, removing port: 3000 from /etc/unbound/unbound.conf and restarting both systemd-resolved and Unbound.

To disable systemd-resolved's listener, create a directory /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d containing a file named, e.g., 10-disable-listener.conf containing the following:
[Resolve]
DNSStubListener=no

Then, to restart both systemd-resolved and Unbound:
systemctl restart systemd-resolved unbound


You'll probably want to stop and disable unbound-resolvconf as well:
systemctl disable --now unbound-resolvconf


Can you advice me on another question on Unbound?

Also another service can now be masked/disable called:unbound-resolvconf. For example run: systemctl disable unbound-resolvconf.service. Assuming you configured systemd-resolved like above.

@MelroyvandenBerg I can't find much documentation about it, what does it do exactly? If I understood correctly it auto-edits /etc/resolve.conf under certain circumnstances? Do you mind expanding on what it does a little bit?

@kos I'm contributor to the Unbound project. At the moment of writing this, the PR is still open: https://github.com/NLnetLabs/unbound-manual/pull/55
After that, this information is available on the official Unbound documentation page. Anyhow, unbound-resolvconf isn't developed by Unbound, but added by the Ubuntu maintainers: https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/amd64/unbound/filelist. And added in 2016: https://launchpad.net/debian/+source/unbound/1.5.9-2. That being said, yes this service is trying to call resolvconf under the hood, but this script most likely fails.

@MelroyvandenBerg Gotcha, thanks! I added that suggestion to my answer

unbound-resolvconf note is now live at: https://unbound.docs.nlnetlabs.nl/en/latest/use-cases/local-stub.html#ubuntu

Appreciate @kos for his answer.
After resolving the port issue, another issue that arose was that the file /etc/unbound/unbound.log did not have the correct file permission, given that "unbound" and not "root" was declared as the username: in /etc/unbound/unbound.conf. Hence, the unbound.service still failed to start.
To resolve this issue, I did the following:

Stopped and disabled unbound.service.
systemctl stop unbound.service
systemctl disable unbound.service


Created a new user called unbound as the primary member of a new group called unbound using this command:
useradd -r -U -u 997 -c Unbound -d /etc/unbound/ -s /sbin/nologin unbound


Changed the group membership of directory /etc/unbound and all its children files and directories from root to unbound with this command:
chgrp -hR unbound /etc/unbound/ 


Gave write-permission to the group membership of directory /etc/unbound and all its children files and directories:
chmod -R g+w /etc/unbound/



Running the command unbound -d -vv -c /etc/unbound/unbound.conf to start the service in debug mode confirmed that the /etc/unbound/unbound.log permission failure was resolved. Thereafter, I restarted unbound.service with the command systemctl restart unbound.service.

It all seems reasonable! Small nit: you need disable only when you don't want the service to automatically start on boot, stop is all that was needed here

As a matter of fact you'll need to run systemctl enable unbound if you want Unbound to automatically start on boot, as your previous disable disabled automatic startup
